# Grid View Insert Query Error

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in asp.net.

I am trying to reference it to insert new data as follows:

```
protected void add_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Txt1")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["CountryNotes"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Txt2")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

When I build the solution I get this error:

> "'TextBox' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
>   "

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Windows.Forms is used in Windows-based applications.
Try removing

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```